# MySQL / PHP figure out visitor frequency from table timestamps

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table which records visitor stats and the time they go on each page. What I'm trying to do is work out the frequency between a selection of time stamps to determine whether it is a human visitor or a bad scraper bot.

The bots obviously can move between pages faster than human visitors do, and so the timestamps have one page visit every 1-2 seconds or so, and this can go on for about 2 hours at a time (and lots of these bots will increase server load too).

The plan was to then either use PHP and do something with the results, or possibly make it all happen with a single SQL query, to see how often a certain IP has visited within the last 2 minutes, and if it's frequency or time difference amounts to only seconds between page views, then put that IP on a bot list.

I've tried the `TIMESTAMPDIFF` which would possibly work if combined with multiple SQL statements to get the `MAX` and `MIN`, and then extracted in PHP and built back into a new query, but I'm trying to work this out to do in the most efficient way.

I first tried to make subqueries with `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` along with `MIN` and `MAX`, but it got too confusing!

So now I've been trying `INTERVAL` but I'm not sure if it's doing what I expect or need.

```
SELECT
    `id`, `ip_addr`, `time_viewed`, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`time_viewed`)  AS unix, 
     UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) as NOWWW,  (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - 120) as one20
         FROM `page_counter`
         WHERE `ip_addr` = '127.0.0.1' AND DATE_ADD(curdate(),INTERVAL 10 SECOND)
         ORDER BY `time_viewed` DESC
         LIMIT 0, 9
```

That's as far as I've got before getting myself too confused with it all!

Any help would be awesome.

---

**EDIT/UPDATE FOR INFO**

OK, so I wrote much of this in a bit of a rush last night, so I'll try to clarify better now what I'm hoping to achieve.

Certain bad bots come across my websites, and are racking up nearly 200 page hits in the space of about 2 hours. Looking at the stats, I can see that the same IP has gone through nearly every page with only a couple of seconds between each hit.

In some cases they have visited nearly 10 pages in under 30 seconds, which is from a stats perspective, is unlikely to be human behaviour.

So my aim is to try and detect this behaviour, if possible, and then redirect the bots to a specific page, or block their IP from the stats at least.

My first thought was to use `TIMESTAMPDIFF` but I think that would take multiple queries to achieve (hence the PHP aspect of this question to filter results with).

For example:

```
SELECT
    `id`, `ip_addr`, `time_viewed`
        FROM `page_counter`
        WHERE `ip_addr` = '109.86.72.137'
        ORDER BY `time_viewed` DESC
        LIMIT 0, 9
```

This then returns the last 9 pages this IP has hit, and the time viewed:

```
id       ip_addr        time_viewed 
1587039 109.86.72.137   2016-03-15 15:20:50
1587038 109.86.72.137   2016-03-15 15:20:45
1587037 109.86.72.137   2016-03-15 15:20:41
1587036 109.86.72.137   2016-03-15 15:20:38
1587035 109.86.72.137   2016-03-15 15:20:29
1587034 109.86.72.137   2016-03-15 15:20:27
1587033 109.86.72.137   2016-03-15 15:20:22
1587032 109.86.72.137   2016-03-15 15:20:15
1587031 109.86.72.137   2016-03-15 15:20:14
```

Then using this info, or if it can maybe be limited to be all pages within 1 minute, if the first and last time stamp can be taken and then used in a `TIMESTAMPDIFF` query, as follows:

```
SELECT
    `id`, `ip_addr`, `time_viewed`, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,'2016-03-15 15:20:14', '2016-03-15 15:20:50') AS diff
         FROM `page_counter`
         WHERE `ip_addr` = '109.86.72.137'
         GROUP BY `ip_addr`
         ORDER BY `time_viewed` DESC
```

This then returns:

```
id      ip_addr         time_viewed         diff    
1586571 109.86.72.137   2016-03-15 13:02:34 36
```

So this particular IP visited 9 pages in 36 seconds, which is makes it quite likely to be bot behaviour.

My problem was being able to dynamically get these first and last timestamps from a `LIMIT` query, and then feed that into a `TIMESTAMPDIFF` query. I don't know if there's a better way to try and get this information or to work out whether a visitor is likely to be a bot by its behavior like this, so I'm open to ideas and better ways of achieving this (purely in MySQL or with a PHP combination).

---

**EDIT #2**
Something I forgot to mention, which actually may be of more help with this - I am also tracking session ID per visitor too, so maybe that can factor into the filtering process?

---

**EDIT #3 - Session IDs**
Considering it more, session tracking may be the best way to go about this:

```
SELECT
    `id`, `ip_addr`, `time_viewed`, COUNT(`sessionID`) as sesh
         FROM `page_counter`
         WHERE `ip_addr` = '109.86.72.137' AND DATE(time_viewed) = '2016-03-15'
         ORDER BY `time_viewed` DESC
```

Returns:

```
id      ip_addr         time_viewed         sesh
1586571 109.86.72.137   2016-03-15 13:02:34 172
```

Meaning that that single IP had 172 unique sessions in the span of that one day. That in itself make it more likely to be a bot than a human visitor, which could be the simpler way to track this (obviously this depends on site traffic, but I wouldn't expect one IP address could get this many sessions in one day??)

**EDIT (again)**
Adding `DISTINCT` to the `COUNT` only returns 15 unique sessions for this IP, which is possibly closer to human behaviour(?)

---

**Update using trincot's example:**

```
SELECT     ip_addr, 
           DATE_FORMAT(time_viewed, '%Y-%m-%d %h') AS hour,
           COUNT(*) AS page_visits,
           (MAX(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_viewed)) - MIN(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_viewed))) 
               / COUNT(*) AS avg_seconds_between
FROM       page_counter
GROUP BY   ip_addr, DATE_FORMAT(time_viewed, '%Y-%m-%d %h')
HAVING     page_visits > 9
ORDER BY   4
LIMIT      9
```

Results in:

```
ip_addr         hour            page_visits avg_seconds_between 
8.37.231.185    2016-01-01 02   35          0.2286
185.5.52.121    2016-03-15 01   324         0.3117
199.15.233.180  2014-03-11 04   22          0.3636
199.15.233.139  2014-03-10 08   22          0.4091
199.15.233.137  2014-01-29 08   12          0.4167
199.15.233.139  2014-02-13 06   12          0.4167
```

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: I don't think you fully understand interval. date_add(curdate(),interval 10 second) means, give me the current date, plus 10 seconds. obviously, this will never match any records, but you are also not comparing it to anything anyway.

Comment: @ryantxr I put PHP because I am open to this being accomplished using a mixture of SQL and PHP, if it's not simple to do just in MySQL.

Comment: @Strawberry I'll edit the question to include some more info, I wrote this in a bit of a rush at the end of the day

Comment: I think you wrongly interpret the count of sessionID values. `COUNT(sessionID)` will count duplicates as well. `COUNT(DISTINCT sessionID)` would count only distinct values, which may in the end be not well-suited to identify bots. I would assume they often work in one session, like humans would...

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to add `DISTINCT`! My brain is still waking up this morning..

Comment: @trincot - updating the query to use `DISTINCT` on the `COUNT` now returns only 15 sessions within that day range on that IP in the above example

Comment: Have you tried using Robots.txt to stop this? I have also blocked crawlers by using their user agent. And if you can figure out which crawler is doing this, you can try contacting them or sometimes they have a way to get yourself off their list. It's sort of a do-not-call list.

Comment: Yeh, the robots.txt is blocking known bots, along with a PHP script backup for those that ignore the txt file. This particular IP in the question, which I haven't blocked yet so I can test on it, has a User Agent of `Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1` so it doesn't even appear as a bot in that sense

Comment: Looking over the records now in the database, it would appear that this IP has 12 different sessions at a time before it changes, all within a couple of minutes. So maybe it can be tackled by checking how many sessions there are per minute, per IP?

Comment: You could do that, but then you customise your query for a specific bot (which you already have detected as bot). It would be better to have a more generic approach as tomorrow you might have a bot that does not change sessions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be sufficient to get what you want:

```
SELECT   ip_addr, count(*)
FROM     page_counter
WHERE    time_viewed >= DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL -10 SECOND)
GROUP BY ip_addr
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT    9
```

It counts per IP address how many pages were consulted during the last 10 seconds. Those with the most page views will be listed at the top.

To get a view over a larger period of time, you could group the statistics per hour, and then select those with the highest visit rate at the top. I did not test this:

```
SELECT     ip_addr, 
           DATE_FORMAT(time_viewed, '%Y-%m-%d %h') AS hour,
           COUNT(*) AS page_visits,
           (MAX(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_viewed)) - MIN(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_viewed))) 
               / COUNT(*) AS avg_seconds_between
FROM       page_counter
GROUP BY   ip_addr, DATE_FORMAT(time_viewed, '%Y-%m-%d %h')
HAVING     page_visits > 9
ORDER BY   4
LIMIT      9
```

The `HAVING` clause might need to be adapted to use a limit that better reflect your needs. It checks that the sample of page visits recorded in one hour is big enough to draw any conclusion.

So if a bot started doing its work at 14:55, with only 4 page visits before 15:00, it will not be detected for the hour slot 14:xx, but it will get detected in the next hour slot if it continued like that for the next 30 minutes (for example).

Comment: This is quite close to what I'm looking for. I'll edit my main question to reflect more what I'm hoping to achieve.

Comment: Answer updated. For now, I did not use the sessionID. I think page visits should normally be a good indication already. Some bots may work in a way that they keep using the same session, so it would not be a very reliable way to detect them.

Comment: This is returned: 
`ip_addr hour page_visits avg_seconds_between 
8.37.231.185 2016-01-01 02 35 0.2286
185.5.52.121 2016-03-15 01 324 0.3117
199.15.233.180 2014-03-11 04 22 0.3636
199.15.233.139 2014-03-10 08 22 0.4091
199.15.233.137 2014-01-29 08 12 0.4167
199.15.233.139 2014-02-13 06 12 0.4167` (edit: ok that doesn't format very well here)

Comment: OK, does that result seem correct to you? I cannot know as I don't have the data...

Comment: I think it might, I'll have to play with it a bit and see if it's filtering things as expected. I'll get back to you :)

Comment: Waiting for your feed-back ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure it's exactly what I need, but it's helped me get going in the right direction better using this as a base, so in that sense I'll accept yours as the answer :)